# How to remove all text properties in a buffer

Tags: text-properties

The function `remove-text-properties` requires a list for the third argument `props` -- e.g., `(remove-text-properties start end '(face nil))`

How can I remove **all** text properties in a buffer in one fell swoop, without necessarily knowing what all of those properties are?

Comment: Sheesh. The answer is on the [same page of the Elisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html) that describes `remove-text-properties`. You should be asking Emacs...

Comment: @Drew -- you are correct -- I missed it by skimming a little too quickly.  The upshot is that I learned the trick of using `inhibit-read-only` in conjunction with `set-text-properties`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this:

```cl
(let ((inhibit-read-only t))
  (set-text-properties (point-min) (point-max) nil))
```

Comment: Yes, that works -- thank you very much.  I am adding your snippet to my custom version of a `fundamental-mode` to essentially restore everything in the buffer to just raw plain text.