# How to disable the org-mode in a buffer

Tags: org-mode, major-mode

For a test purpose, I enabled the org-mode by `M-x org-mode` in a buffer (e.g., in scratch buffer). How to disable it? Doing again an `M-x org-mode` does not turn it off.

Comment: How about replacing it with the desired mode -- `M-x fundamental-mode`?  See also the contents of the function `fundamental-mode` -- i.e., `(kill-all-local-variables) (run-mode-hooks)`.  I take it a step further and remove overlays, and I remove text properties, and some other stuff -- see:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12527/2287

Comment: This is no doubt a duplicate of other questions about "turning off" a major mode, but I don't have time now to hunt for a duplicate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Doing again an M-x org-mode does not turn it off.

This convention is for minor-modes - Doing a M-x "minor-mode-name" again disables that minor mode. org-mode is a major mode. When you do this, emacs has no clue which major mode to go into. There must be a major mode always active.

So, rather than disable org-mode, you have to think in terms of which major mode to go into. Fundamental mode, as described in a comment is a choice as good as any.

Comment: The scratch buffer is in lisp interaction mode when starting Emacs so that would be a good candidate as well