# Revert `font-lock-face` changes

Tags: font-lock, text-properties

I have a custom face defined as

```lisp
(defface my-underlined
  '((t (:underline "red")))
  :group 'my-group)
```

At some place I underline some words with something like

```lisp
(add-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0) '(font-lock-face my-underlined)))))
```

What would be a correct way to revert this text properties set on some words (or on all words on demand) as well as restore their syntax highlight that might have existed before? Nothing with `font-lock-` seems to work. What would be a correct way to underline and revert?

A function `underline-region` doesn't seem to work. It just inserts `^H_` into the text.

Comment: BTW, instead of `(add-text-properties .. .. '(PROP VAL))` you can use `(put-text-property ... 'PROP 'VAL)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Emacs Lisp manual section on [removing text properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html).

`remove-list-of-text-properties` seems to do what you want.

See [related discussion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12526/how-to-remove-all-text-properties-in-a-buffer) here on the Emacs StackExchange.